# strange corruption in rawpy.imread

Tags: image-processing, dng

I intended to read a DNG formatted image with the code rawpy.imread(path), however it returned me with a error message, saying `unknown file: data corrupted at xxxxxxx (7-digit number)`.

Following this error, I found the program is still able to continue to run anyway, and the DNG image is not a flat one, since when visiting its property of `raw_image_visible`, it returned me with a ndarray of four channels. I have the lastest version of rawpy package (0.16.0) under Windows 10 environment.

I shared the photo via [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hOh-9ihWgiU_LlX7WuHtQsczL9_4id5A/view?usp=sharing). I have no idea how I can address this issue. Any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: Try sharing the image - probably with Google Drive or Dropbox or similar. Show your code as well and state your OS etc.

Comment: I get the same error at 7419756 using macOS. I can't find the error message in the `rawpy`  source so maybe it comes from `libraw`. Maybe try checking the file with Adobe DNG converter.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks. The device I used to take photo is iPhone 12 Pro and now I am contacting Apple Support to see if the problem lies in the device itself. Are you able to find other DNG formatted photos and have a try with rawpy.imread?